# add 2 different maps to Firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 maps called `favorite` and `recommend`. Basically, both `favorite` and `recommend` contain a map `movie_ID: rating`. Here is how i want it.

[image: Here is what is should look like]

Here is my code to do that:

```
def writeFavorite(dta, uid):
    user = db.collection('user').document(uid)
    for i in dta:
        row = {
            'favorite': {i['movie_id']: i['rating']}
        }
        user.set(row, merge=True)


def writeRecommend(dta, uid):
    user = db.collection('user').document(uid)
    for i in dta:
        row = {
            'recommend': {i['movie_id']: i['rating']}
        }
        user.set(row, merge=True)


writeRecommend(test, uid)
writeFavorite(test2, uid)
```

Here is the result:
[image]
I have 2 test lists, each contains 10 `{movie_id: rating}`. However, when i run the code above, instead of creating 2 map like what i want, it some how joins 2 maps together, it creates empty `favorite` and 20 sample `recommend`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show the values for `test`, `test2` and `uid`? I used your code and it does what you want on my side.

Comment: sure, uid is just documentID that i set which is str('1000'). For `test` and `test2`, i will update `movie.txt` and `movie2.txt` respectively in my post

Comment: Sorry it was my dumb fault. While creating 2 lists test and test2, i accidentally forget to type `2` for the test2 so i append 20 sample to `test`. The result is `test2` has 0 sample and `test` has 20

Comment: I will delete this soon. Thank you very much @orby!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by  **An.on** that issue has been resolved by simple correction :

> While creating 2 lists test and test2, he accidentally forget to type
> 2 for the test2 so he append 20 sample to test. The result is test2
> has 0 sample and test has 20

For more information you can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data).